# Running a code from an instance in Google Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am new to google cloud composer. I have some code in google cloud compute engine - 
for eg: test.py

Currently I am using Jenkins as my scheduler - and I'm running the code like below

`echo "cd /home/user/src/digital_platform &&/home/user/venvs/bdp/bin/python -m test.test.test" | ssh user@instance-dp`

I want to run the same code from google cloud composer.

How I can do that..

Basically I need to ssh to an instance in google cloud and run the code in an automated way using google cloud composer.

Comment: Check this out :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457592/airflow-how-to-ssh-and-run-bashoperator-from-a-different-server

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [SSHOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator.SSHOperator) might be something that might work for you. This operator is an Airflow feature, not Cloud Composer feature per se.

The other operator that you might want to take a look at before making your final decision is [BaskOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/operator/bash.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a DAG (workflows), Cloud Composer schedules only the DAGs that are in the DAGs folder in the environment's Cloud Storage bucket. Each Cloud Composer environment has a web server that runs the Airflow web interface that you can use to manage DAGs.

[Bash Operator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags#bashoperator) is useful to run command-line programs. I suggest you follow the Cloud Composer [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/quickstart#viewing_the_dag_in_the_airflow_web_interface) which shows you how to create a Cloud Composer environment in the Google Cloud Console and run a simple Apache Airflow DAG.