# Moving data from a database to Google Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, google-cloud-composer, data-integration

I am trying to figure out a way to move data in batches(not streamed in) from on-prem database (Oracle) to Google Bigquery.

I am trying to do this via Google Cloud Composer however I understand that I need to get data into GCS first before I can use composer to move it to BigQuery.

What is the best way to move data from on-prem DB to GCS. or is there a service in Google cloud that allows me to move data directly from the DB to Bigquery?

Can this be better done with Cloud Dataflow instead? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think you are mixing a little bit tools/services with the main goal that is the migration. So before anything I'm going to explain some concepts:

1) **Cloud Composer** is just a GCP product that provide Airflow as Service, and what is Airflow? an **orchestration platform where you can programmatically author, schedule and monitor workflows.** Therefore, this is useful once you have multiple pipelines, jobs or task to orchestrate. It could be used for the initial migration, but is not necessary a mandatory service to be used.

2) **DataFlow** is a great product from GCP, that uses [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org) as its main pipelining language, so you can deploy batch or stream pipelines. Dataflow is the alternative of classic products/frameworks such as Spark or Hadoop if you want to have a more Cloud Native experience in GCP. The next image it's the recommendation about when to use DataProc (Spark, Hadoop, etc as a service) or Dataflow:

[image]

Now that we understand the terms here it comes the answer: It depends. So these services can help you in the process but each infrastructure is quite unique. For instance:

- Can we stop services and make the migration? Or should it happen with the database accepting requests?
- How long it should take? max time?
- It's your DB behind firewalls? VPN could affect?
- It is a [lift and shift](https://www.vxchnge.com/blog/understanding-lift-and-shift) approach? I mean, are you going to copy paste directly or is there going to be data refactoring to use BigQuery in the proper way?

So as you can see it depends a little bit from your needs and current infrastructure. However, I'm going to tell you what we did in our company:

In my case I kind of made both approaches: Lift&Shift and Data Refactoring. The reason fo doing that was to provide the business with something to query, while we were busy refactoring the data architecture. The way that we did the first one was moving just as it is the tables from our MSSQL database to BigQuery. The solution was a set of python scripts to copy the schemas and recreate the tables on the other side (table by table in small batches).

**Note:** This process could be done using DataFlow for instance, however if your DB is behind Firewalls and it requires VPN access and so on, you will have a bad time trying to make it work.

The suggested way by Google is to make dump of your tables in GCS and then you can reconstruct them using the create table from source option in BigQuery (that it behaves similar as Athena in AWS). However, keep in mind that BigQuery just recognises Avro, parquet, JSON, CSV and ORC formats. Meaning that your DB dump should export in one of these formats. If you use something like JSON or CSV, Google BigQuery is smart enough to auto detect your schema, nevertheless!!! it's not perfect and it will make a lot of assumptions based on the first 100 rows. If you use avro or parquet, the schema will be defined by those files, so you will reduce the risk of false positives.

**Note:** In the case of Oracle you can "export" to CSV or JSON using something like this https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/fast-generation-of-csv-and-json-from-oracle-database

So in general there are plenty options to tackle this issue and also a lot of things to consider. This is a document from google about migration from TeraData to BigQuery, but in general it works for any other kind of migration:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/td2bq/td-bq-migration-overview

Good luck!

Comment: thx  Juan Urrego
My answers
Can we stop services and make the migration? Or should it happen with the database accepting requests?  
_Migration should be ongoing and we don't want to stop DB and yes it can take requests_
How long it should take? max time? _We expect to load few tables at a time for now it's an ongoing process_
It's your DB behind firewalls? VPN could affect? _Yes DB is behind firewalls_
It is a lift and shift approach? I mean, are you going to copy paste directly or is there going to be data refactoring to use BigQuery in the proper way?
_mostly lift&shift_

Comment: I understand I would seem outside code or app to move data from DB to GCS as the first landing area and later I could use Cloud Composer or Dataflow based on things you explained. 
To do the first bit of moving data is it something like I write an app and make it run on prem or in GCP and have it move tables to GCS? I would prefer not to write a separate connector of sorts if  there is a way to do it from Airflow or Dataflow itself with some coding of course. If so can you point me to some links for that.

Comment: Ok, so for `Migration should be ongoing and we don't want to stop DB and yes it can take requests ` I would say to you need to have a read replica of your Oracle DB. That way, you can run queries without affecting your current users. Given that you also need to migrate the new data that is coming, I would use something like PubSub + DataFlow to insert the new data on real time. So in that order of ideas, you create batch processes for the historical data and receive the new one in real time (keeping old and new in synch)

Comment: For `Yes DB is behind firewalls It is a lift and shift ` be careful of making the VPN tunnel with your services. For me in that scenario, I would create some scripts in that will run in the private network and open the outbound traffic to BigQuery or GCS (depending your approach)

Comment: For `I understand I would seem outside code or app to move data from DB to GCS as the first landing area and later I could use Cloud Composer or Dataflow based on things you explained.` it's not necessary to have something "outside", you could potentially create a job that one of AirFlow's operator could execute. This custom operator connects with an agent in your current infrastructure for instance. Therefore you can use AirFlow/composer to orchestrate your complete workflow. I mean, the message is just be careful with those security constraints before you start coding

Comment: For instance you can use the SSH hook to connect to your private infrastructure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39457592/airflow-how-to-ssh-and-run-bashoperator-from-a-different-server

Comment: Thx again. So by this  `you could potentially create a job that one of AirFlow's operator could execute. This custom operator connects with an agent in your current infrastructure for instance.`  do you mean I would need to install an agent to receive requests from the Airflow job? Isn't it possible with Airflow/Dataflow to use some thing like a Java JDBC/Python code to read from the DB and create temp files in GCS or perhaps move directly to BigQuery my final stop?

Comment: Before talking technical implementation, just talk about use cases. Why using big query instead of cloud SQL? Are you aware about bigquery constraint? Latency and denormalization?

Comment: Yes, we want it in BigQuery mainly to help drive our analytics and we are fine with latency and denormalzation.

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule your data migrations to GCS outside of Cloud Composer. Then create a DAG with GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor which pokes GCS in intervals to check if the file arrives. Then you can copy your data to BigQuery with GCSToBigQueryOperator.